# ASP.net Identity Disable User

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Using the new ASP.net Identity in MVC 5, How do we disable a user from logging in? I don't want to delete them, maybe just disable their account for a time period.

Does anyone have any ideas on this as I don't see a status column or anything on the ASPNetUsers table.

Comment: IMHO it would be wrong to close this question. The OP is not asking for code. The question is about if it is possible or not to disable/lock an account using the Asp.net identity framework. Asking the OP to provide an "attempted solution" to his problem seems unreasonable in this case, if he could he would not have to ask in the first place. I also think that the fact that even a security expert such as Brock Allen asks a very similar question in his blog post http://brockallen.com/2013/10/20/the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-of-asp-net-identity/ shows that this is a relevant question.

Comment: how is this off-topic?  I have the exact same question.

Comment: I'm so surprised at how incomplete ASP.Net Identity is in its current state.  Why provide the columns in the schema for something you don't support?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update**: As CountZero points out, if you're using v2.1+, then you should try and use the lockout functionality they added first, before trying the solution below.  See their blog post for a full sample: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/08/05/announcing-rtm-of-asp-net-identity-2-1-0.aspx

---

Version 2.0 has the IUserLockoutStore interface that you can use to lockout users, but the downside is that there is no OOB functionality to actually leverage it beyond the pass-through methods exposed by the UserManager class.  For instance, it would be nice if it would actually increment the lockout count as a part of the standard username/password verification process.  However, it's fairly trivial to implement yourself.

**Step #1**: Create a custom user store that implements IUserLockoutStore.

```cs
// I'm specifying the TKey generic param here since we use int's for our DB keys
// you may need to customize this for your environment
public class MyUserStore : IUserLockoutStore<MyUser, int>
{
    // IUserStore implementation here

    public Task<DateTimeOffset> GetLockoutEndDateAsync(MyUser user)
    {
        //..
    }

    public Task SetLockoutEndDateAsync(MyUser user, DateTimeOffset lockoutEnd)
    {
        //..
    }

    public Task<int> IncrementAccessFailedCountAsync(MyUser user)
    {
        //..
    }

    public Task ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(MyUser user)
    {
        //..
    }

    public Task<int> GetAccessFailedCountAsync(MyUser user)
    {
        //..
    }

    public Task<bool> GetLockoutEnabledAsync(MyUser user)
    {
        //..
    }

    public Task SetLockoutEnabledAsync(MyUser user, bool enabled)
    {
        //..
    }
}
```

**Step #2**: Instead of UserManager, use the following class in your login/logout actions, passing it an instance of your custom user store.

```cs
public class LockingUserManager<TUser, TKey> : UserManager<TUser, TKey>
    where TUser : class, IUser<TKey> 
    where TKey : IEquatable<TKey> 
{
    private readonly IUserLockoutStore<TUser, TKey> _userLockoutStore;

    public LockingUserManager(IUserLockoutStore<TUser, TKey> store)
        : base(store)
    {
        if (store == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("store");

        _userLockoutStore = store;
    }

    public override async Task<TUser> FindAsync(string userName, string password)
    {
        var user = await FindByNameAsync(userName);

        if (user == null) return null;

        var isUserLockedOut = await GetLockoutEnabled(user);

        if (isUserLockedOut) return user;

        var isPasswordValid = await CheckPasswordAsync(user, password);

        if (isPasswordValid)
        {
            await _userLockoutStore.ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(user);
        }
        else
        {
            await IncrementAccessFailedCount(user);

            user = null;
        }

        return user;
    }

    private async Task<bool> GetLockoutEnabled(TUser user)
    {
        var isLockoutEnabled = await _userLockoutStore.GetLockoutEnabledAsync(user);

        if (isLockoutEnabled == false) return false;

        var shouldRemoveLockout = DateTime.Now >= await _userLockoutStore.GetLockoutEndDateAsync(user);

        if (shouldRemoveLockout)
        {
            await _userLockoutStore.ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(user);

            await _userLockoutStore.SetLockoutEnabledAsync(user, false);

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private async Task IncrementAccessFailedCount(TUser user)
    {
        var accessFailedCount = await _userLockoutStore.IncrementAccessFailedCountAsync(user);

        var shouldLockoutUser = accessFailedCount > MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout;

        if (shouldLockoutUser)
        {
            await _userLockoutStore.SetLockoutEnabledAsync(user, true);

            var lockoutEndDate = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now + DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan);

            await _userLockoutStore.SetLockoutEndDateAsync(user, lockoutEndDate);
        }
    }
}
```

**Example**:

```cs
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(string userName, string password)
    {
        var userManager = new LockingUserManager<MyUser, int>(new MyUserStore())
        {
            DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = /* get from appSettings */,
            MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = /* get from appSettings */
        };

        var user = await userManager.FindAsync(userName, password);

        if (user == null)
        {
            // bad username or password; take appropriate action
        }

        if (await _userManager.GetLockoutEnabledAsync(user.Id))
        {
            // user is locked out; take appropriate action
        }

        // username and password are good
        // mark user as authenticated and redirect to post-login landing page
    }
```

If you want to manually lock someone out, you can set whatever flag you're checking in `MyUserStore.GetLockoutEnabledAsync()`.

Comment: The lockout date stored in the database should be UTC, based on the name.  You compare to a local DateTime.Now.

Comment: Correction: I didn't notice it was compared to a DateTimeOffset.

Comment: GetLockoutEnabledAsync does not check if the user is locked out. As the name suggests, it checks if lockout is ENABLED.

Answer (score 39):

```
await userManager.SetLockoutEnabledAsync(applicationUser.Id, true);
await userManager.SetLockoutEndDateAsync(DateTime.Today.AddYears(10));
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer as OP asked how to disable a user and this is by far the simplest solution.

Comment: Use await userManager.SetLockoutEndDateAsync(applicationUser.Id, DateTimeOffset.MaxValue);

Comment: how can unLockUser??

Comment: According to the code if you supply a `DateTimeOffset` of `MinValue`, it will set a `null` in the DB and it should be unlocked.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a new class, which should be derived from IdentityUser class. YOu can add a boolean property in the new class and can use this new property of take care per check for login process. I also done it pretty well. I might wanna take a look at : [blog](http://www.codingeek.com/dotnet/codenode-identity-an-implementation-of-asp-net-identity/)

Answer (score -3):

`UserManager.RemovePasswordAsync("userId")` will effectively disable a user. If the user has no password he will not be able to log in. You will need to set a new password to enable the user again.

Comment: are there no better options than this?

Comment: Then the user resets his password and voila !