# soft delete in asp.net identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm new to asp.net.   How to store the value of IsDeleted to database?

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(string id)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {     
        var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(id);

       //set IsDeleted  to true
        user.DeleteUser();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: *Why* do you want to soft delete an account? It doesn't make sense in a *business* context. If you want the account to be disabled or locked, disable or lock it. Deleting an account means *deleting* it and shouldn't be done unless there are legal reasons to do so.

Comment: [Duplicate here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32951260/how-to-disable-a-user-in-identity-2-0). You can add an `IsEnabled` property and check it during signin. Another option is to lockout the user with an infinite lockout period

Comment: Disabling or locking an account is the right solution. I used that IsEnabled property and it's working beautifully. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct way to soft delete the user account. Instead, we can lock the account.

Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803109/asp-net-identity-disable-user) stackoverflow question, has more details.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a field to the `userTable` in database which shows the status, if the user is deleted the value will set to `true` and by default the value will be false.

Comment: That is the *question*, not the answer.

Comment: i suggest adding field to database table to check if the user is deleted. @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: Which is what the OP *asks*. `How to store the value of IsDeleted to database?` How *do* you create that field? How *do* you set that value?

Comment: instead of deleting the user using `user.DeleteUser();` you can edit status, `user.status = fasle`. which `status` is the property that shows the status of the user, deleted or not. @PanagiotisKanavos